# How to create dynamic title tag in asp.net based on select name in datalist

Tags: asp.net

How to create dynamic title tag in asp.net based on selection name in data list control.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever may b your selection end, but to display the title tag from server side code, You need to add "runat = server" in your html page. Please follow the below line of code.

**HTML Page**

```
<head runat = "server">
...
</head>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Page.Title = "My sample";
```